# Did New Republic leaders ask Luke to create a New Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars

We know that: "For over a thousand generations, the Jedi knights were the guardians of peace and justice in the Old Republic". My question is, did the New Republic's leadership (besides Leia Organa) actually want new Jedi knights to serve in a similar capacity as their predecessors had? If so, did the New Republic leaders charge Luke with the task of creating a New Jedi Order?

Comment: Using strictly OT movies canon - given the rebellion's fondness for "may the force be with you" it is implicit that the Jedi Returning would be welcomed.  We don't get much of the regular person's belief in the force other than it is clearly there.  I wish Rogue One had emphasized more the comeuppance athiest Krennic had from Darth Vader after persecuting Jyn Erso's mom for her beliefs.

Answer (score -1):

According to Legends, and the Jedi academy trilogy, Luke makes a speech to the senate, and get overwhelming support, and approval to rebuild the jedi. Although some senators are a bit concerned, Luke persuades them.

Comment: Can you provide a quote that backs this up?

Comment: Sorry im a bit late for this, but im gonna need to dig around to find the book for the quote, although one member (I believe crix madine sorry if i spelled it wrong) asks luke about jedi turning to the dark side. been a while since i read Jedi search but ill find the quote.

Answer (score -2):

My assumption would be that not likely.

The Empire had 20 years of propaganda where Jedi's were seen as traitors. Even if you didn't buy it it would be hard to see them like more than a failure: they failed to protect the galaxy, and were not there during the rebellion.

So I would assume the new senate would see Jedis as part of a failed and flawed system that resulted in all of this mess. Its unlikely that they would want to "return to how things were", therefore no New Jedi Order.

Comment: This feels like a total guess. Can you back it up with any evidence?

Comment: As I opened the post, its an assumption, so yes, you feel right, an assumption has no evidence, therefore its a guess.

Comment: Imperial propaganda also painted the old Republic in general as ineffective but that didn't stop the Alliance to Restore the Republic, now did it?

Comment: The "Old Republic" was written after the "Republic" was already in place, so you can't really use that as analogy. In this case the New Republic is written after the Republic, which does serve as background. The writing order (and known facts) does have an impact.

Comment: @Jalex23 You missed the point.  The point was the limit of effectiveness of imperial propaganda, that by your logic no one should have wanted a republic back.

Comment: I said "unlikely" not impossible.